# JQuery wrong ajax done callback fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a strange situation going on with ajax callbacks.

Call A works fine (I can see the server calls in the right place), and the done callback is fired correctly.

Call B call works fine (I can see the server calls in the right place), but then A's done callback is fired!

Here's the code:
A:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#beta_signup_form').submit(function() {
        var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'), //submits it to the given url of the form
            data: valuesToSubmit,
            dataType: "JSON", // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function(json){
            console.log("in the beta signup form success function!!!!");
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("--------> beta signup modal callback error");
        });
        return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
});
```

and code B:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#twitter_sign_up').submit(function() {
        var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'), //submits it to the given url of the form
            data: valuesToSubmit,
            dataType: "JSON", // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function(json) {
             console.log("in success for modal B...");
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("--------> modal B callback error");
        });
        return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
});
```

What's going on here???

Comment: I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Can you paste HTML code here.

Comment: Are you sure that it happens with the code you've shown us? Because it looks perfectly fine. Even more - since they are in separate `$(document).ready` handlers, then it is impossible for them to see each other.

Comment: you should use `var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize(), $this = $(this);` in the `submit` callback  and then refer to `$this` in your `$.ajax` call instead of `$(this)`.

Comment: this is how you create an ajax fiddle with jQuery for us to see what you're doing next time [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/Mk9Bc/)

Answer (score 0):

OH man... I just figured it out.

So I had:

```
<div id="twitter_sign_up">
  <form id="beta_signup_form" ...>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

My fault for copying html!

Comment: Very nice, haha. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: This is what ruled out that being the problem for me, *"Call B call works fine (I can see the server calls in the right place)"* I guess they were both calling the same location? or did you not actually check the location it was posting to